# how can I input a literal string into istream?

Tags: c++, iostream

I am attempting to load a structure using an istream.  Is there a way an istream can read/ignore specific characters or can I enforce this somehow?  This is currently what I have:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    unsigned int  identifier;
    float         value;
    float         bob1;    
    float         bob2;    

    std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, MyStruct& s)
    {
        in >> identifier >> value
           // Can I do this?
           >> '[' >> bob1 >> ',' >> bob2 >> ']';
    };
};
```

Comment: You just want to ignore the brackets? What do you want to do if the brackets aren't there?

Comment: Right now I don't care if I bomb.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks for the reference

Comment: Read into char variables na1 and na2 and ignore them.

Comment: Yeah, that makes good sense as well but I want them to be specifically those characters and not just any character.

Comment: Which is why I asked what to do if they aren't.